# binding <tab> to company complete

Tags: key-bindings, completion, ivy, company

I would like  to *always* trigger company suggests. When I use:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<tab>") 'company-complete))
```

It breaks ivy's completion in the minibuffer. How can I prevent this? I would like to set the above key binding globally, even for the scratch buffer, but not to break the current completion used in the minibuffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting that binding into `company-mode-map`:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'company
  (define-key company-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") 'company-complete))
```

`company-mode` is not active in the minibuffer, so it shouldn't be affected.

Comment: If I try this in emacs 29 I get an error that indicates that 'company-mode-map' doesn't exist.

Comment: That's probably because `company` hasn't been loaded at that point. So while technically correct, the answer was probably less helpful that it could have been. I've updated it now with a more plug-and-play snippet.